# Failed to establish a new connection in wsl when i use pip install

Tags: python, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to install flask-sqlalchemy within the virtual environment on my ubuntu subsystem (WSL) on Windows 11, using the following command:

```
 pip install flask-sqlalchemy
```

however i recieve an error in console window.

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff5c27dff10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/flask-sqlalchemy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff5c2620280>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/flask-sqlalchemy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff5c2620520>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/flask-sqlalchemy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff5c26206d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/flask-sqlalchemy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff5c2620880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/flask-sqlalchemy/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask-sqlalchemy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask-sqlalchemy
```

I think it is related with network connection in my Ubuntu subsystem. I try on Standalone Linux system and it seems to be work. How i can solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i finnaly resolve my issue. I post below steps to solve this problem.
I checked my fireewall settings. It was not an issue.
i dont use proxy so i skipped the proxy issue.

i checked ping from the console window

```
ping google.com
```

it displayed

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I found a solution. Seems like my DNS server can't find an address associated to the URL i am passing. I got errors because the resolv.conf file was  not set up in my Ubuntu Subsystem.

**solution:**

in wsl Ubuntu Linux type commamnd

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

add nameserver and save file

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```